# JMS @Discriminator filed doesn't appear if specific group is serializing

Tags: symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, discriminator, jms-serializer

I'm using Symfony 2.8, FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle.

## Problem

Discriminator field `type` of `Document` entity doesn't apear in serialized model when I serialize specific group ("api" group in folowing example) of entity `Citizen`.

## Doctrine Entities

Document:

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
…    

/**
 * @JMS\Discriminator(field = "type", map = {
 *      "doc1"              = "MyBundle\Entity\Document1",
 *      "doc2"              = "MyBundle\Entity\Document2"
 * })
 */
class Document 
…
```

Citizen:

```
class Citizen
{
 …
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Document",
     *      cascade={ "PERSIST", "REMOVE" },
     *      orphanRemoval=true,
     *      mappedBy="citizen"
     * )
     *
     * @JMS\Groups({"api"})
     */
    private $documents;
    …
```

## What I get

```
{
…
"documents": [
    {
        "number": "000000",
        "date": "01.01.1970",
        "serial": "0000",
        "place": ""
    }
],
…
}
```

## What I need

```
{
…
"documents": [
    {
        "type": "doc1",
        "number": "000000",
        "date": "01.01.1970",
        "serial": "0000",
        "place": ""
    }
],
…
}
```

If I remove specific serialization group, then `type` field is present in serialized output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found [issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/506) on github. 
Seems for now, workaround with `Default` group is needed, see [lordelph's comment](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/506#issuecomment-192184830)